# How to extract values from a row based on special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help to achieve below output

COLUMN value:-

```
Document Name for File: Updated from Q1 - answer to Q1 - answer (Abhi up)); Version: Updated from V5.2 to V5.7;Updated from No to Yes
```

Required output:-

```
Document Name for File: Updated from Q1 - answer to Q1 - answer (Abhi up))
Version: Updated from V5.2 to V5.7
Updated from No to Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016 or higher, you can use `string_split()`.

```
SELECT ltrim(rtrim(ss.value))
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS APPLY string_split(t.nmuloc, ';') ss;
```

For version 2008 or higher you can use `nodes()` and `value()` via a conversion to an `xml`.

```
SELECT ltrim(rtrim(nodes.node.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')))
       FROM (SELECT convert(xml, concat('<x>', replace(t.nmuloc, ';', '</x><x>'), '</x>')) xml
                    FROM elbat t) x
            CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('/x') nodes(node);
```

For both ways use `rtrim()` and `ltrim()` to remove leading or trailing spaces.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b8041fbaa1907d3989bc2ef31dcc0a2a)